# Android webview app crashes after 5 hours

Tags: android, memory-leaks, out-of-memory, android-webview

My app keeps craching after 5 hours. I'm displaying a webview in android with 8 video's. It must have something to do with memory problems but i can't find where it is located. I'm using loadDataWithBaseURL to display the webview.

#### Error

```
08-14 20:01:23.581 5552-5552/? E/ActivityThread: Service com.google.android.gm.EmailMigrationService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.aj@3cd1a5a6 that was originally bound here
android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.google.android.gm.EmailMigrationService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.aj@3cd1a5a6 that was originally bound here
    at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:1077)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:971)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.bindServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1791)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1774)
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:539)
    at com.android.emailcommon.service.ah.a(SourceFile:181)
    at com.android.emailcommon.service.ah.e(SourceFile:224)
    at com.android.email.service.n.c(SourceFile:161)
    at com.google.android.gm.EmailMigrationService.onHandleIntent(SourceFile:221)
    at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see here that you are `binding` a service. Consider `unbinding` it in `onDestroy()`

Comment: What do I have to unbind. To solve it. I'm sorry i'm not that used to android.

Comment: where are you binding the service in your code? Please update your question.

Comment: I'm not binding com.android.emailcommon.service anywhere. That's the weird part.

Comment: @NickVanBakel Please refer to this link: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services to bind/unbind your service